# Old version of Xcode still in /Developer/Applications - can I delete /Developer completely?

Tags: ios, xcode, upgrade

Today I noticed that I have the latest version of Xcode on my Mac, one in /Developer/Applications, the other in /Applications.

The one in /Applications is the latest, App Store-installed version; the /Developer/Applications is from 2011. I was wondering if I can delete the complete /Developer folder, or that the new Xcode still uses that location?

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Young can delete it, all required Libs, Apps and other stuff is now integrated in the XCode.app Package. Most of the other applications you have found in the /Developer Folder have moved to the Menu Xcode > Open Developer Tool.

Also a lot off stuff wich is not ned in first place, has been moved to the Apple Developer download portal (More developer tools under Open developer tools) and must be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me back over 2 GB of space!